# Does $X_1,...,X_n$ being a random sample from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ $\implies \frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}$ ~$t_{n-1}$?

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Does $X_1,...,X_n$ being a random sample from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ 
$\implies \frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}$ ~$t_{n-1}$?

If so does the above imply that a standard normal divided by the square root of a $\chi^2$ variable with $a$ degrees, has a $t$ distribution with $a$ degrees of freedom?

Comment: If $X$ is standard normal, **independent** of $Y\sim \chi^2_n$, then it is *by definition* $\frac{X}{\sqrt{Y/n}}\sim t_n$. This explains the first result you state assuming standard notations.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I think the OP defined $t_\nu$ differently (e.g. via its pdf) and need to show the result as a consequence.